# how do jw player play the videos with unclear type

Tags: jwplayer

i want to create a site like yotube . for playing videos i Use jw player .
My problem is that the video address does not indicate video type

for example my video link is (video type is flv):

```
 http://myweb.com/player/browse.php?u=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&b=0&f=norefer
```

and jw player dont play this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JW6, and the PHP script that you are loading as the player's "file" variable is returning a FLV file, all you need to do is set the player's "type" variable to "flv"

If you are using JW5, set the player's "provider" variable to "video"